# Can scopes be wrapped in parentheses and return a value in C?

Tags: c

I looked up the definition of `MIN` on Mac OS X and found this:

```
#define MIN(A,B) ({ __typeof__(A) __a = (A); __typeof__(B) __b = (B); __a < __b ? __a : __b; })
```

It's not so obvious at first, but when it expands, it turns into something that looks extremely strange to me:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
// int min = MIN(a, b);
int min = ({
    int __a = (a);
    int __b = (b);
    __a < __b ? __a : __b;
});
```

This is, indeed, a scope wrapped into an expression that "returns" the value of the last expression. It seems to work, at least with clang, with pretty much arbitrary code inside the scope:

```
int a = ({
    time_t x = time(NULL);
    if (x % 3 == 1)
        x++;

    x % 10;
});
```

I had never seen this before, and I was wondering if it's standard. I know for a fact that Visual Studio won't accept it, but then again, Visual Studio is stuck with C89, so that's not very telling.

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)

Comment: @icepack, it's not a block. Blocks need to be invoked with the parentheses operator and start with a `^` character.

Comment: FWIW, I can't find anything in [ISO 9899:1999](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). (This doesn't mean that it's not there, but it's certainly not in what I thought are the obvious places.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a GCC extension to standard C called [Statement Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).  Yes, you can use it if you only need to support GNU compilers (and it is cross-platform).  If you need to stick to standard C, you won't use the notation.

Comment: Found it: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html thanks.