# Function like macros returning a value

Tags: c, macros

Recently came across following examples which returns a register read __ret but without a return statement

```
#define READWORD(offset)       ({ \
                 unsigned short __ret=0;\
                 __ret = readw(offset);\
                 __ret; \
                 })
```

Did Google on the same and found that function like macros can return value. Is it safe to assume that last statement "_*ret" is equivalent to returning a value?
What if i have another statement after "*_ret" which changes __ret value. Which one would get returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scopes be wrapped in parentheses and return a value in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571112/can-scopes-be-wrapped-in-parentheses-and-return-a-value-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

This is using a GCC extension called [Statement Expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

You can use it unless you need to be portable to compilers other than GCC (and Clang/LLVM).

Comment: This is what i pick up from the link "The last thing in the compound statement should be an expression followed by a semicolon; the value of this subexpression serves as the value of the entire construct. (If you use some other kind of statement last within the braces, the construct has type void, and thus effectively no value.)" As i understand the last statement is the entire computed value of the macro. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: That's correct...In this example, I'm not sure what the benefit of the statement expression is compared with `#define READWORD(offset) ((unsigned short)readw(offset))` which is portable and does the same job AFAICS.  In general, there are things you can do in Statement Expressions that you can't do without.

Answer (score 3):

Let's break this down. For example, let's see what READWORD(1) will do. The preprocessor will insert this:
(
    {
    unsigned short __ret=0;
    __ret = readw(1);
    __ret;
    }
)

Now we can see what it's up to. We're just calling a function readw with a parameter (1) and assigning it to an unsigned short. After which we just have the line __ret; Although a perfectly valid statement it doesn't appear it does anything. But read on!

Everything is out of scope after the final }.

But, the enclosing () make all the difference. Elegantly the whole thing is an expression that has the value __ret. So you can assign a varaible to it. This makes the whole thing remarkably stable in macro arguments.

Does this help unpick?

Comment: You've omitted the parentheses around the expanded text.  And it is a GCC-specific extension over standard C; it is not portable except to Clang/LLVM (which is based in part upon GCC).

Comment: Oops. Put it in! I'd never use it in practice as it's an idiom too far and confuses source control maintainers. I mean, my explanation is pretty confusing isn't it?